# Como faço para exibir uma DIV ao passar o mousa sobre outra DIV mantendo a mesma posição de abertura?

Tags: css

Vou explicar baseado na imagem abaixo que fiz para ficar mais fácil de se entender.

Na imagem abaixo tenho um banner (cor cinza) e outro maior na cor vermelho.

O funcionamento seria o seguinte: Quando passar o cursos do mouse sobre o banner de cor cinza, abriria o banner de cor vermelho. Mas, sempre o banner vermelho abriria em uma mesma coordenada (posição) independente do tamanho do banner de cor cinza, como podem ver abaixo.

Espero que possam me ajudar.

Muito Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `position:fixed;` para manter um elemento sempre em uma mesma posição na tela. Segue um exemplo, passe o mouse na área cinza para exibir o banner vermelho. Espero ter ajudado :D

```js
$("document").ready(function (){
  $(".cinza").mouseenter(function (){
     $(".vermelho").show();
  })
  
  $(".cinza").mouseleave(function (){
     $(".vermelho").hide();
  })
})
```

```css
.container{
  display:block;
}

.cinza{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:gray;
}

.vermelho{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  width:100px;
   height:100px;
  background:red;
  display:none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cinza"></div>
  <div class="vermelho"></div>
</div>
```